# React iOS on window

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to code for iOS on Windows but I've noticed that all the tutorials have been saying that you need Xcode to code react for iOS. Is there any way to do this and have iOS simulator? And can I have a camera app in any sources?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you need Xcode, so Mac OSX is required.